# How to integrate WIX logs with CruiseControl.Net dashboard?

Tags: wix, cruisecontrol.net

I have my CI build process successful creating a MSI using WIX by calling heat, candle and light.  But when there is a problem I have to login to the build server and view the log files for the WIX utilities.  I'd like to be able to view those logs from the dashboard like I can view the MSBUILD log.

Is there a way to integrate the logs produced by WIX into the CruiseControl.Net dashboard?

I using CruiseControl.Net (v1.5.7256.1) and WIX (v3.5.2312)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiX has Votive which provides VS integration / MSBuild support.   Is there a reason you are calling candle and light directly instead of using this?  If you used this your WiX logs would be MSBuild logs just like the rest of your build.

Comment: WiX/Votive 3.0 does not, 3.5 does.

Comment: Still working out all the details but integrating the wixproj into our build solution is going to work.  thanks!